# Observe click event on a synced map in Leaflet/RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm creating a mapping visualization in RShiny, and I'm trying to detect a map shape click. I know that you can do this by using `observeEvent`, but my issue is that I'm using `leafsync` to synchronize my maps, so I have to wrap my Leaflet maps in a `renderUI`. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage('CS4All and CTE Progress Visualization',
             tabPanel('Map',
                      div(class='outer',
                          sidebarLayout(
                            mainPanel(
                              uiOutput('synced_maps')
                            )
                          )
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$synced_maps <- renderUI({
    
    # --- CS4ALL MAP 
    cs4all_map <- leaflet() %>%
      setView(lat=40.730610, lng=-73.935242, zoom = 10) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      addPolygons(data         = ctecscrs_geo,
                  stroke       = TRUE,
                  color        = '#808080',
                  weight       = 1) 

    # --- CTE MAP
    cte_map <- leaflet() %>%
      setView(lat=40.730610, lng=-73.935242, zoom = 10) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      addPolygons(data         = ctecscrs_geo,
                  stroke       = TRUE,
                  color        = '#808080',
                  weight       = 1) 

    # --- DEMOGRAPHICS MAP
    dem_map <- leaflet() %>%
      setView(lat=40.730610, lng=-73.935242, zoom = 10) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      addPolygons(data         = csd_dem_geo,
                  stroke       = TRUE,
                  color        = '#808080',
                  weight       = 1)
    
    sync(cs4all_map, cte_map, dem_map)
  })
}
```

I tried adding the following both inside and outside of the renderUI function:

```
 observeEvent(input$cte_map_shape_click, {
      click <- input$cte_map_shape_click
      print(click$id)
    })
```

and in both instances, nothing printed to the console. Does anyone know if it is possible to observe events on synchronized maps in Leaflet/RShiny?

Comment: Hi Janice. Did you find a solution ?